# Numpy array as video in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a set of edge images that I have extracted from videos (using `cv2.Canny`). So the size of the array is `TxHxW`. Where `T` is time steps, and the following parameters are height and width.

Currently the way that I display the output on a **Jupyter Notebook** is with the following code:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
import imageio

imageio.mimwrite('test2.mp4', edges, fps=30)
HTML("""
<video width="480" height="360" controls>
  <source src="{0}">
</video>
""".format('./test2.mp4'))
```

I feel life the writing to file is probably unnecessary and that there might be a better way. If there is please let me know. The emphasis is on displaying in a Jupyter notebook.

If you need a testcase let `edges = np.random.randn(100, 80, 80)`.

### Solution 1:

Thanks to the comment from @Alleo below. With Ipython 7.6+ you can do the following:

```
import imageio; 
from IPython.display import Video; 
imageio.mimwrite('test2.mp4', edges, fps=30); 
Video('test2.mp4', width=480, height=360) #the width and height option as additional thing new in Ipython 7.6.1
```

This still needs you to write to file though.

Comment: I think you want to use `import imageio;
from IPython.display import Video;
imageio.mimwrite('test2.mp4', fragment, fps=30);
Video('test2.mp4')`

Comment: Thanks. This was certainly a lot cleaner option.

Answer (score 6):

A fast way of doing this (to be used for debug purpose for instance) is to use `matplotlib inline` and the matplotlib `animation` package. Something like this worked for me

```py
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython.display import HTML

# np array with shape (frames, height, width, channels)
video = np.array([...]) 

fig = plt.figure()
im = plt.imshow(video[0,:,:,:])

plt.close() # this is required to not display the generated image

def init():
    im.set_data(video[0,:,:,:])

def animate(i):
    im.set_data(video[i,:,:,:])
    return im

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=video.shape[0],
                               interval=50)
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

The video will be reproduced in a loop with a specified framerate (in the example above I set the animation interval to 50 ms, i.e., 20 fps).

Please check my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060422/fast-way-to-display-video-from-arrays-in-jupyter-lab) for more details.