# fast way to display video from arrays in jupyter-lab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to display a video from some arrays in an notebook in jupyter-lab. The arrays are produced at runtime. What method to display the images can deliver a (relatively) high framerate? Using matplotlib and imshow is a bit slow. The pictures are around 1.8 megapixel large. 
Above some very small example to visualize what I want to achieve.

```py
while(True): #should run at least 30 times per second 
    array=get_image() #returns RGBA numpy array  
    show_frame(array) #function I search for
```

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way (to be used for debug purpose for instance) is to use `matplotlib inline` and the matplotlib `animation` package. Something like this worked for me

```py
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython.display import HTML

# np array with shape (frames, height, width, channels)
video = np.array([...]) 

fig = plt.figure()
im = plt.imshow(video[0,:,:,:])

plt.close() # this is required to not display the generated image

def init():
    im.set_data(video[0,:,:,:])

def animate(i):
    im.set_data(video[i,:,:,:])
    return im

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=video.shape[0],
                               interval=50)
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

The video will be reproduced in a loop with a specified framerate (in the code above I set the interval to 50 ms, i.e., 20 fps).

Please **note** that this is a quick workaround and that `IPython.display` has a `Video` package (you can find the documentation [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html)) that allows you to reproduce a video from file or from an URL (e.g., from YouTube). 
So you might also consider storing your data locally and leverage the built-in Jupyter video player.

Comment: Amazing solution! This works perfectly with open-ai gym rendered images and should get more upvotes.